# mocha chai test cases are not working to resolve state in ui-route

Tags: angularjs, mocha.js, chai

I need to test url path which i am redirecting through angularJs

```
$state.go('myPage');
```

I tried to get state in mocha chai

```
it('should load the page.', inject(function ($state) {
var state = $state.get('myPage');
```

But i am getting error "Could not resolve 'myPage' state '' "

more details

Controller

```
var pageRedirection = function () {
  var absUrl = $location.absUrl(),
  url = absUrl.split('/'),
  length = url.length,
  pageURL = url[length-2],
  state;
  state = SELECT_LINE_CONST.SELECT_RATE_PLAN_STATE;
  $state.go(state+channel);};
```

config file

```
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$stateProvider.state('myPage', {
  url: '/myPageData/WEB',
  templateUrl: function () {
    return 'scripts/html/views/myPage.html';
  },
  controller: 'myPageCtrl',
  css: 'styles/lazy-load/myPage.css'
});
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');})

.constant('SELECT_LINE_CONST', {
'SELECT_RATE_PLAN_STATE': 'myPage'
```

});

Mocha chai

```
it('Testing buttonClick function if url === myPage', function() {

  var state = 'myPage';
  var objState = $state.go(state);
  $rootScope.$digest();
  selectLineService.pageRedirection();
  expect(selectLineService.pageRedirection()).to.be.ok;
});
```

Any idea how to fix it ..

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Are you testing whether or not a controller redirects to a state? Or did I misunderstand?

Comment: I am testing my redirect function with $state.go('myPage'); in controller with mocha chai. but getting error.